# Error in google cloud compute engine: can't select machine type for new instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am creating a new instance and the CPU dropdown seems to be broken, check a screencast here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3AG2ilJVv-JajNCM0xkSEpFa0E/view

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Are you still having the same problem? Are you still on the trial period?

Comment: @codaniel it's fixed now, but I still am in the trial period yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very satisfying answer, but Google support has confirmed that they already have a bug logged for this (**EDIT**: <s>There is currently no ETA for a fix.</s>Google informed me that they deployed a fix.  Unfortunately I couldn't test it personally because I had already converted to a full account which got around the problem.).  The workaround they suggested is to use the `gcloud` command line tool, which of course is a tedious solution.  Until they fix it, here are some tips for using gcloud.

List of available machine types plus zones:

```
gcloud compute machine-types list
```

List of zones:

```
gcloud compute zones list
```

The create command has a million options, but it starts `gcloud compute instances create`.  The full syntax is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create).

Comment: Thanks. It comes and goes by the way.

Comment: @NaguibIhab I wish it would just go.  It hasn't worked once yet for me.

Comment: Switching to AWS becomes really tempting in those moments